# Encrypt vbs file using some algorithm

Tags: vb.net, encryption, vbscript

I need to encrypt vbs file using a cryptographic algorithm. I read about converting it into vbe file, but is there any other way to do it?

Regards

Comment: Can we ask why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to do this and have the file remain executable without the need for some third-party application.